# Leaflet.Draw save marker to DB

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to save marker to DB with fields

**lat**, **lon** , **marker description.**

If there is only one marker on the map everything is fine, but when I add a second one, my code generate 2 sql-s instead 1 and duplicates 1st added marker info.

This is my code:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
  var type = e.layerType;
  var layer = e.layer;
  var marker_lat = layer._latlng.lat;
  var marker_lng = layer._latlng.lng;

// Here I open Popup to save Marker discription
    $('#point_description').modal('show');

    // Here save marker lat, Lng + marker description 
    $(document).on('click', '#save_point', function () {
        var point_description_text = $('#point_description_text').val();
        insertPlaques(marker_lat, marker_lng, point_description_text, modal_window);
    });


  drawnItems.addLayer(layer);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'draw:created' function is going to be called everytime a new shape is created by Leaflet.Draw.  Everytime that method is called, a new on 'click' listener is added to the '#save_point' element.  So the second time 'draw:created' is called (and the user clicks '#save_point'), two listeners will be invoked.  The third time, three listeners will be invoked.

You should either remove your click listener using `off()` after the insertPlaques method is called, or consider using a method like `one()` to add your click listener instead of `on()` (https://api.jquery.com/one/)